# Read the memory in a FPGA

Tags: memory, fpga, intel-fpga

I'm using a de0-nano board with an Altera Cyclone IV FPGA. My design has a hardware part and a software one. The hardware one is implementing a qsys project with a Nios II cpu that is running the software part. The qsys project has a dual-port memory. One port is connected to the cpu and the other is exported so the hardware can write to it.
My design is not working as I want. I don't know whether it's because of the hardware or the software so I'd like to read the memory by another way and I don't know which tool I can use.
If someone can help me...

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use Insystem Memeory Content Editor in Quartus to read the content inside Block Ram.It will work from Cyclone III family. But no problem you are using Cyclone IV

Comment: And how do I do that?

Comment: @RomainMichard  check this below link for the details. https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CB0QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.altera.com%2Fliterature%2Fhb%2Fqts%2Fqts_qii53012.pdf&ei=aVH_U9ncLoWgugTTn4AY&usg=AFQjCNFNrUMMFAou2FDZLumRlf0jm7sqqQ